# Laravel 10, Vite and Vue 3

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js, vite

I need help implementing Vue.
Can't figure out how to interact with the template using Js while outside the template itself.

I have the following files:
app.blade.php file which contains the `<div id="app">` container and also, outside the container it has a `@yield('scripts')` so I can load custom scripts for every template.

login.blade.php inside that file im rendering a Vue template using this:

```
  <bs-button
      type="button"
      text="{{ __('Login') }}"
      class="btn btn-primary"
      icon="fa-solid fa-arrow-right-to-bracket"
      id="login-btn"
      :auto-handle-click="false"
      ref="loginButton"
  ></bs-button>
```

So that is inside the "app.blade.php" #app div.

Then, inside the "login.blade.php" Im loading a separate file called "login.js".

Inside that login.js I want to be able to toggle the "loading" property of the #login-btn but I don't know how to call the 'toggleLoading" method.

This is the bs-button vue template code:

```
<template>
    <button :class="[{ 'disabled': loading }]" @click="handleClick">
        <span v-if="loading">
            <i class="fas fa-spinner fa-spin"></i>
        </span>
        <span v-else>
            <i v-if="icon" :class="icon"></i>
        </span>
        {{ text }}
    </button>
</template>

<script>
    import { ref } from 'vue';

    export default {
        props: {
            text: {
                type: String,
                default: 'Button'
            },
            icon: {
                type: String,
                default: ''
            },
            autoHandleClick: {
                type: Boolean,
                default: true
            }
        },
        setup(props, { emit }) {
            const loading = ref(false);

            const handleClick = () => {
                if (!loading.value && props.autoHandleClick) {
                    loading.value = true;
                    emit('click');
                }
            };

            const toggleLoading = () => {
                loading.value = !loading.value;
            };

            return {
                loading,
                handleClick,
                toggleLoading
            };
        },
        methods: {
            toggleLoading() {
                this.toggleLoading();
            }
        }
    };
</script>
```

I want to be able to access the "toggleLoading" method from another js file, and when the form is submitted, disable the button:

```
import $ from 'jquery';

$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#login-form').on('submit', (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        
    });
});
```

Is there a way to do this?. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I've found a solution.

It seems that I needed to add this to the Vue template:

```
mounted() {
    const buttonRef = this.$props.id;
    window.buttonComponents = window.buttonComponents || {};
    window.buttonComponents[buttonRef] = this;
},
```

and also this to its props:

```
id: {
    type: String,
    required: true
}
```

So now im able to call the `toggleLoading()` method from `login.js` like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#login-form').on('submit', (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        window.buttonComponents['login-btn'].toggleLoading();
    });
});
```